# Why does it seem like the ideal photodiode model leads to a violation of conservation of energy?

Tags: diodes, photodiode, solid-state-devices, device, device-characteristics

**Short version of my question:**

Roughly speaking, the output power from a properly biased ideal photodiode feeding a resistor is quadratic with the optical input power, with seemingly no limit. So at some input power level the output power will be greater than the input. I think this is clear since fundamentally the current from an ideal photodiode is proportional to the input optical power. I have supplied some more detailed analysis below to make this clearer.

Obviously I either made a mistake or there is something I haven't taken into account that takes care of this. My feeling is that some non-ideality of the photodiode I haven't taken into account will limit the maximum voltage across the diode, preventing us from achieving more power out than in. My questions are the following:

1. Is the reason for my paradox a problem with my derivation or a problem with my diode model?
2. If it is a problem with my diode model, what is the most natural non-ideal addition to the model to take care of this (ie. reverse bias breakdown? leakage resistance?)
3. If it is a problem with my diode model, at a more fundamental level (ie. a condensed matter physics level) why must this non-ideality always be present such that there is no violation of conservation of energy? In other words, what physical reason prevents us from just making a "really good" diode that can produce more power out than in?

**Here is a more detailed description of the situation I'm discussing:**

Let's say I have a photodiode absorbing some modulated light. This can be written in the form

$$
P_{\text{in,optical}}(t) = P_{\text{ac}} \cos(wt) + P_{\text{dc}}
$$

Since the power can't be negative it's clear

$$
P_{\text{dc}} \geq P_{\text{ac}}
$$

That means the minimum "optical DC power" is

$$
P_{\text{dc,min}} = P_{\text{ac}}
$$

We will use this later.

Now let's say this photodiode is attached to a circuit in the following configuration

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUDg0v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The basic idea here is that we have a reverse bias applied to the diode, and an ac path over a resistance to extract the AC power. Using the ideal photodiode model we can transform this into an equivalent schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOjBje.png)</sup>

Here I_{ac}(t) and I_{dc} are photocurrents produced by P_{ac} and P_{dc}, and I_{bias} is the current produced by the bias voltage. We can say the photodiode has responsivity R, and treat the large inductor and capacitor as simple AC and DC blocks respectively.

We are also assuming that the photodiode is biased deeply in the reverse bias regime such that I_{bias} is approximately a constant equal to the saturation current of the diode, I_{s}. In order to maintain this regime, the voltage over the diode (from anode to cathode) must be below some amount, V_{max}. This will be some slightly negative amount ie. -1 V. The voltage over the diode is clearly the sum of the voltage over the capacitor and the resistor. The voltage over the resistor is given by I_{ac}(t) r, and the voltage over the capacitor is just the negative of the bias voltage, -V{bias}. Thus

$$
I_{\text{ac,peak}}  r - V_{\text{bias}} < V_{\text{max}}
$$
$$
P_{\text{ac,peak}} R r - V_{\text{bias}} < V_{\text{max}}
$$
$$
V_{\text{bias}} > P_{\text{ac}} R r - V_{\text{max}}
$$
$$
V_{\text{bias,min}} = P_{\text{ac}} R r - V_{\text{max}}
$$

So basically when we increase the input optical power, we need to linearly increase the reverse bias of the diode to prevent the big voltage swings over the output resistor from forward biasing the diode. This will be useful soon.

There's a couple of power inputs in this system:

- the power from the DC biasing of the diode
- the dc optical power input
- the ac optical power input

There's only one power output:

- The power over the resistor

To see the conservation of energy violation I will show you that the power output may be greater than the power input.

Power input from biasing the diode:
$$
P_{\text{bias}} = V_{\text{bias}} I_s
$$
To consume the minimum power, let's use V_{bias,min} from previously:
$$
P_{\text{bias}} = (P_{\text{ac}} R r - V_{\text{max}}) I_s
$$
$$
P_{\text{bias}} = P_{\text{ac}} r (R I_s) + (-V_{\text{max}} I_s)
$$

Average minimum power input total from all sources:
$$
P_{\text{in}} = \text{time_average}(P_{\text{in,optical}}(t)) + P_{\text{bias}}
$$
$$
= P_{\text{dc,min}} + P_{\text{bias}}
$$
$$
= P_{\text{ac}} + P_{\text{ac}} r (R I_s) + (-V_{\text{max}} I_s)
$$
$$
= P_{\text{ac}} (1 + r [R I_s]) + (-V_{\text{max}} I_s)
$$

Average power output from all outputs (note I'm using I_{ac,peak} here instead of an RMS current so I divide by 2):
$$
P_{\text{out}} = \frac{I_{\text{ac,peak}}^2}{2} r
$$
$$
= \frac{P_{\text{ac}}^2 R^2}{2} r
$$
$$
= P_{\text{ac}}^2 r \frac{R^2}{2}
$$

The main problem this presents is
$$
P_{in} \approx \propto P_{\text{ac}}
$$
$$
P_{out} \approx \propto P_{\text{ac}}^2
$$

This is made clearer if we take r to infinity (in other words, "for large r")
$$
\lim_{r \to \infty} P_{\text{in}} = P_{\text{ac}} r (R I_s) \propto P_{\text{ac}}
$$
$$
\lim_{r \to \infty} P_{\text{out}} = P_{\text{ac}}^2 r \frac{R^2}{2} \propto P_{\text{ac}}^2
$$

If it's not completely clear this is an issue yet:

$$
\lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{P_{\text{out}}}{P_{\text{in}}} = \frac{P_{\text{ac}} R}{2 I_s}
$$

So for a sufficiently large modulated photonic input, eventually the output power will be larger than the input.

Comment: *the output power from a properly biased ideal photodiode feeding a resistor is quadratic with the optical input power* Where did you read that? That's obviously wrong. The output power from a photodiode is roughly proportional to the input power within the linear region. Nothing much to it. Outside the linear region, the slope may be increasing, but it'll obviously still stay under the limit defined by Pout<=Pin.

Comment: From my understanding, optical input power of P leads to a current of PR, across a resistance of r the electrical power out is thus (PR)^2*r.

Comment: It most definitely does not. Knowing this, you should be able to spot the mistake. There's no need to mess with Pac, set it to zero, use Pdc in the RMS sense.

Comment: What do you think the current out would be then? Maybe that's where my misunderstanding is.

Comment: The current from a photodiode into a resistor is nonlinear relative to input optical power. That why, for linear measurements, you connect the photodiode into a virtual ground, and *then* measure the current. I think the source of confusion was that you assumed that photodiode input power is measured with a resistor. You know what that's used in? Electro-optical squaring and rooting circuits :)

Comment: For reference I'm including a dc biasing scheme here, so the non-linearity from the forward biasing of the diode is negligible. That's an important part of my question.

Comment: No forward bias is implied to get nonlinear current out of a photodiode. A resistor does that just fine all by itself. It's not hard to measure with a very crude setup basically on a kitchen table if you wish.